# Failing to format flashdrive to UDF

Tags: usb-drive, udf

I'm trying to create a UDF partition on a flash drive to install grub2 (to boot ISOs from)

```
~$ export DSK=/dev/sdd
# wipe the disk
~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=${DSK} bs=512 count=2048
~$ sudo sgdisk --zap-all ${DSK}

# create partition for udf
~$ #sudo parted -s ${DSK} mklable msdos
~$ #sudo parted -s ${DSK} -a optimal unit MB -- mkpart primary 1 -1
~$ (echo o; echo n; echo p; echo 1; echo ; echo ; echo t ; echo 6 ; echo w) | sudo fdisk -b 512 ${DSK}

~$ sudo mkudffs --media-type=hd --blocksize=512 ${DSK}1
trying to change type of multiple extents
```

Comment: Just as a side note, depending on the flash drive (SD cards), it is *unwise* to use anything but FAT (or exFAT). Using something else on SDXC makes them a lot slower, and throws off wear leveling considerably. It is also against spec. If you need a boot loader on there, I suggest SYSLINUX.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with `mkudffs` on a partition, but on the device itself it worked flawlessly. Running `strace` on `mkudffs` showed that it was seeking to a few places and trying to read 1 byte, but getting nothing back. dvd+rw-format flat out refused to work on partitions.

What worked for me was to create a UDF filesystem essentially anywhere, in this case the USB stick without a partition, `/dev/sdd`

```
mkudffs --media-type=hd --vid=VOLUME --lvid=VOLUME --blocksize=512 /dev/sdd
```

save at least the beginning of that filesystem somewhere:

```
dd if=/dev/sdd bs=1024 count=40000 | gzip > /tmp/udf
```

create the partition (of type 6):

```
fdisk  /dev/sdd
```

plaster the partial, non-fitting filesystem on the partition:

```
gunzip -c  /tmp/udf  | dd of=/dev/sdd1
```

then make a proper filesystem:

```
mkudffs --media-type=hd --vid=UDF32GB --lvid=UDF32GB --blocksize=512 /dev/sdd1
```

Answer (score 1):

> trying to change type of multiple extents

This problem should be fixed in the last mkudffs 2.0 version from [udftools](https://github.com/pali/udftools) project.

Make sure that partition which is going to be formatted as UDF has at least 300 sectors. Partitions/disks with less sectors cause problems for UDF.